# XSD: root element ERROR

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have a small problem when I was trying to create XML Schema.
When I generated it ,I got this error message: 
A root element must be specified.

So what is the problem ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<complexType name="yazartipi">
    <sequence>
        <element name="isim" type="string"></element>
        <element name="soyad" type="string"></element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="kitaptipi">
    <sequence>
        <element name="ad" type="string"></element>
        <element name="sene" type="int"></element>
        <element name="kategori" type="string"></element>
        <element name="yazar" type="tns:yazartipi"></element>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="no" type="int" use="required"></attribute>
</complexType>

<complexType name="kitaplartipi">
    <sequence>
        <element name="kitap" type="tns:kitaptipi" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<element name="kitaplar" type="tns:kitaplartipi"></element>
```

Comment: Is that your whole XML Schema file or is it an extract?

Comment: @softwariness it is my whole xml schema. I just want to try how to generate it. But I couldnt :s

Comment: I have created an xml schema with your snippet and there was no issues. Can you please elaborate how you are generating it and in which step you are getting the issue?

Comment: The XML schema was not "generated" - it was written. You have been informed about the missing `<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"...>`. - But what program produced the error message when you were trying to do what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After cleaning-up your XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Kitaplar"
        xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Kitaplar"
        elementFormDefault="unqualified"
        attributeFormDefault="qualified">

  <complexType name="yazartipi">
    <sequence>
        <element name="isim" type="string"></element>
        <element name="soyad" type="string"></element>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="kitaptipi">
    <sequence>
        <element name="ad" type="string"></element>
        <element name="sene" type="int"></element>
        <element name="kategori" type="string"></element>
      <element name="yazar" type="tns:yazartipi"></element>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="no" type="int" use="required"></attribute>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="kitaplartipi">
    <sequence>
        <element name="kitap" type="tns:kitaptipi" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <element name="kitaplar" type="tns:kitaplartipi"></element>
</schema>
```

You should find that an XML document such as this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tns:kitaplar xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Kitaplar"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/Kitaplar try.xsd">
  <kitap tns:no="0">
    <ad/>
    <sene>1</sene>
    <kategori/>
    <yazar>
      <isim/>
      <soyad/>
    </yazar>
  </kitap>
</tns:kitaplar>
```

Will validate successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the message. A "root" element is an element that wraps the entire document.

Example with no root:

```
<tag>
  <value1>V</value1>
</tag>
<tag>
  <value1>X</value1>
</tag>
```

Example with a root element:

```
<tags>
  <tag>
    <value1>V</value1>
  </tag>
  <tag>
    <value1>X</value1>
  </tag>
</tags>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the assumption that you have put the whole .xsd file here. In that use case you have not used the xs:schema element that defines a schema as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
</xs:schema>
```

In the schema above we use the standard namespace (xs), and the URI associated with this namespace is the Schema language definition, which has the standard value of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.

You should also refer the following link for further reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_example.asp